# insert and update two tables using procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to Create the relevant stored procedure handle a purchase.To insert data into itemPurchase table and update Item table.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[ItemPurchaseProc]
    --@id int
    @ItemPrice float,
    @Itemqty int
AS
BEGIN
    insert into ItemPurchase(ItemPrice, ItemQty, ItemTotal) 
    values (@ItemPrice, @Itemqty, @ItemPrice * @Itemqty)

    Update Item
    Set StkCount =- @Itemqty 
END
```

This is what i have written.and following are the two tables. Tell me how to create this procedure. Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
    ItemCode AS 'IT' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(id as varchar(10)), 3) PERSISTED,
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Item PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemCode),

    Item_Desc varchar(30),
    Quantity int,
    MinStkLvl int,
    SalesPrice float,
    StkCount int
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ItemPurchase
(
    InvCode AS 'IN' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(id as varchar(10)), 3) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT FK_InvCode1 
        FOREIGN KEY (InvCode) REFERENCES Invoice(InvCode) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1), 
    ItemCode AS 'IT' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(id as varchar(10)), 3) PERSISTED,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ItemCode1 
        FOREIGN KEY (ItemCode) REFERENCES Item(ItemCode) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ItemPrice float,
    Itemqty int,
    ItemTotal float 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not clear what you need.

However, The 2 operations on the tables need to be in a transaction.

-Your business logic to update MinStkLvl should be added here. Maybe fire a trigger(?) or call another stored proc...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HandlePurchase]
(
    @itemId                 int,
    @qty                    int,
    @double                 price
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     BEGIN TRY
```

--Write your updates to the table here
--check agains min stock level before updating the items table
--Your business logic

```
     COMMIT
     END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH
```

Comment: invoice is created at the time of selling products to the particular customer. The invoice should have an Invoice No, Date, Customer Details, Items purchased ,Item Code, Description, Price, Qty and the Total Price. Once the invoice is created, the current stock count should be updated immediately. When the stock count reaches to the minimum stock level automatically that re-order item details should be sent to a new table in the database. i want a procedure to create a new invoice and handle a purchase with these updates..